# Parse data into JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have one specific problem that I'm having difficulty Googling the answer for.

This is the code:

```
records.forEach(function(record){
    var personID = record.id;
    var personsInterest = record.interest;

    console.log(personID);
    console.log(personsInterest);
    console.log();
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
138
death note

146
poop

138
poop

146
rick and morty

138
rick and morty

138
lil peep

145
420
```

I would really like the code to store the data like this

```
[
    {
        id: "138",
        interests:["death note","poop","rick and morty","lil peep"]
    },
    {
        id: "146",
        interests:["poop","rick and morty"]
    },
    {
        id: "145",
        interests:["420"]
    }
]
```

where they are ordered by the length of the interests array

Comment: Hint: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: This won't be enough, take a look at Array.reduce

Comment: Object properties don't have an order, and the sample output isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @RobG Object properties have an order, you just cannot rely on the order.

Comment: Show `records`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Annotated in comments.

```js
const records = [{
    id: 138,
    interest: 'death note'
  },

  {
    id: 146,
    interest: 'poop'
  },

  {
    id: 138,
    interest: 'poop'
  },

  {
    id: 146,
    interest: 'rick and morty'
  },

  {
    id: 138,
    interest: 'rick and morty'
  },

  {
    id: 138,
    interest: 'lil peep'
  }
];

const sorted = records.reduce((all, record) => {
  const person = all.find(p => p.id === record.id);
  //If already exists person now contains existing person
  if (person) {
    person.interests.push(record.interest);
    //add new interest
  } else all.push({
    id: record.id,
    interests: [record.interest]
    //creates new person object
  });

  return all;
}, []).sort((a, b) => b.interests.length - a.interests.length);
//sorts based on length of interest array

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Loop main arr using forEach
2. Created result arr
3. Add new object to result arr
4. Else push to interest array

```js
let records = [
  {
    id: 138,
    interests: "death note"
  },
  {
    id: 146,
    interests: "poop"
  },
  {
    id: 138,
    interests: "poop"
  },
  {
    id: 146,
    interests: "rick and morty"
  },
  {
    id: 138,
    interests: "rick and morty"
  },
  {
    id: 138,
    interests: "lil peep"
  },
  {
    id: 145,
    interests: "420"
  }
];

let result = [];
records.forEach(record => {
  if (result.filter(item => item.id == record.id).length == 0) {
    // check whether id exists in result array, if not push object to result array
    result.push({ id: record.id, interests: [record.interests] });
  } else {
    //if id already exists in result array, push interest to interest array of that id
    result.forEach(v => {
      if (v.id == record.id) {
        v.interests.push(record.interests);
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Pxmwjp?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Use sort method with a suitable compareFunction to sort your array. `arr.sort(compareFunction(a,b))`

Sort method takes a function and sorts the elements of the array according to the return value of the function supplied. Let's call the function `compareFunction(a, b)`.
If the return value of `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0: a comes first.
If the return value of `compareFunction(a, b)` is more than 0: b comes first.
If the return value of `compareFunction(a, b)` is 0: does nothing.

You want the element which has the higher interest.length comes first. So we can return `b.interest.length - a.interest.length`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```js
var records = [{
    id: 10,
    interest: ["poop", "rick and morty"]
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    interest: ["eminem", "snoop dog"]
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    interest: ["death note", "poop", "rick and morty", "lil peep"]
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    interest: ["god of war"]
  },
];

records = records.sort((a, b) => b.interest.length - a.interest.length);

console.log(records);
```